# What does a c preceding permissions indicate?

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I'm trying to figure out what kind of files I'm dealing with on a partition of a device as part of a security investigation. This partition has a filesystem type of 'none' according to `df`. There are a number of files with `crw-rw----` or other ugo permssions. I'm trying to figure out what `c` means. I know that `d` indicates a directory and `l` indicates a symlink from experience. I'm also seeing some preceded with b.

Overall, the most helpful thing would probably be a chart explaining all the different characters that can appear here and what they mean. I've not been able to find anything like that.

Comment: Man I forgot how much I hated this site.

Answer (score 0):

The `c` represents a character device such as a mouse, speaker, webcam, etc that transfers data in bits or bytes which are also know as characters hence the `c`.

Answer (score 0):

`man ls` will give you the chart of "-l" entries.  These will be the first column in your `ls -l` listing.

```
       -     Regular file.
       b     Block special file.
       c     Character special file.
       d     Directory.
       l     Symbolic link.
       p     FIFO.
       s     Socket.
       w     Whiteout.
```

Comment: `man ls` didn't give me the entries, it was the first thing I checked.

Comment: @jaredad7, what system are you running?  It seems concerning that your man page doesn't show that information.